# What is the formal definition for a clean working directory in git?

Tags: git

Is there some formal definition of what constitutes a "clean working directory" in git?

Do people mean it as:

1. The working directory matches the index.
2. The working directory matches the current branch HEAD (assuming the head isn't dangling).
3. Either (1) or (2) depending on the context.

Furthermore, do people ever say a "clean index", and does that just mean that the index matches the current branch HEAD?

Comment: I think the answer is *no, there's no formal definition*. My understanding of that phrase is that I'm on HEAD of the branch, and my branch is also synchronized with whatever is in the upstream repository.

Comment: My understanding is different: *clean* working directory means a working directory that contains only files tracked by `Git` and that everyone sees (no build outputs, test outputs etc.). BTW, I hope you know that there is a `git-clean` command?

Answer (score 0):

Almost.  It is:

4. Both (1) and (2)

When your working directory is clean, the directory matches the index and the index is HEAD.